# Add field value to datefield in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

**Parent Model:**

```
id = auto_generated
add_me = IntegerField()
```

**Child Model:**

```
id = ForeignKey(Parent)
my_date= DateTime(auto_now_add=True)
```

and,

```
today = django.util.timezone.now()
time = today - timedelta(days=10)
```

now I want to retrieve records as:

```
child.objects.filter(my_date__lte= time + 
(timedelta(days=1)*F('id__add_me')))
```

Everthing works fine **except**:

```
(timedelta(days=1)*F('id__add_me'))
```

I am using **MYSQL**:
I get:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError:
 (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
 server version for the right syntax to use near
 '* `parent`.`add_me`))))' at line 1")
```

Query Generated is like:

```
SELECT*  FROM `child INNER JOIN `parent` ON
 (`child`.`id` = `parent`.`id`) WHERE
  ( `child`.`my_date` <= ((2018-07-30 09:11:18.670900 
  + (INTERVAL '86400.000000' SECOND_MICROSECOND * `parent`.`add_me`))))
```

As you can see `*` (multiplication) is with `INTERVAL`. 
I hard coded query putting the `parent`.`add_me` inside the `INTERVAL` and got it right,
 how can I do so via Django? i.e. `DATE_ADD` in django

**I want to reduce days from a `datetime` field, where days are stored in master table field.**

Maybe it doesn't work with MYSQL, so please provide an alternative solution to such.

## UPDATED:

Somehow I found error by writing **MYSQL** query as:

```
SELECT * FROM child INNER JOIN parent ON" \
child.id = parent.id WHERE
child.my_date<= '" + str(time) + \
"' + INTERVAL parent.add_me DAY "
```

The problem was with single quotes (`'`) i.e. in `mysql` for `<=` the `datetime` shall be within single quotes else won't work. i.e.
`2018-07-30 09:11:18.670900` shall be written as
 
`'2018-07-30 09:11:18.670900'` if adding with `INTERVAL`,
But as queries are generated by Django, how do I achieve that?

Comment: Not as easy as I thought. I deleted my answer because none of the alternatives I have come up with would work :-(

Comment: Hope you'll, sir. I went writing MYSQL statement and found the reason as mentioned in the UPDATED question section, probably that can help you